# glXSwapBuffers blocks until new X-events are fired

Tags: multithreading, qt, opengl, x11

We have a really strange bug in our software. Call of glXSwapBuffers will block every now and then until some X-events are sent (mouse hovering over window/keyboard events). It seems that the bug is identical to [Qt QGLWidget OpenGL rendering from thread blocks on swapBuffers()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028108/qt-qglwidget-opengl-rendering-from-thread-blocks-on-swapbuffers) which was never properly solved. We have a same kind of situation.

In our application we create a multiple number of windows because our application needs to work with multiple screens. Each of our window is basically QWidget which has a class derived from QGLWidget as its only child. Each window has its own rendering thread attached which executes OpengGL-commands.

In this setting, application just halts every now and then. It continues normally if we feed X-events to it (moving the mouse over windows/push keyboard buttons). Based on the debugger info glXSwapBuffers() blocks somewhere inside the closed driver code.

We haven't confirmed this behaviour on NVidia cards, only with AMD-cards, and it is more likely to appear when using multiple AMD-cards. This suggests that the bug may come from the GPU-drivers.

I would like to know has any other bumped into this and has somebody even managed to solve this.

Comment: I'm currently developing an application that follows a very similar scheme. My system hat a multi GPU NVidia card (GeForce GTX 690) and uses shared contexts to update PBOs and textures from worker threads. However rendering happens only from the main GUI thread and glXSwapBuffers is called only there. Should I notice any problems I'll note it here.

Comment: After updating to the newest AMD-drivers this is vanished at least partly. The test cases which were sure to block with earlier drivers do not block anymore. I am not sure if this is fixed in the newest driver release, since I couldn't find any information about the changes made to the newest drivers.